# Abstract base class member variables

Tags: c++, qt

I have an abstract base class "Company" and 2 subclasses "notForProfit" and "forProfit" that derive from "Company".   Both sub classes have member variables "name" and "dateFormed".  Is it possible to define those 2 member variables in "Company" and have the 2 subclasses inherit "Name" and "DateFormed" to use in their constructors?

Comment: They can be in the base, accessible in the derived classes, but not directly in the initialiser list; you construct the base class by name, so give the base class a constructor taking arguments for these members. Whether or not this is a good idea, to have data in the class that is supposed to define the interface, I'm not sure. Also, you may end up in the weird world of `protected`.

Comment: The biggest question you need to ask is: what's the difference between `ForProfit` and `NotForProfit` subclasses? Do you need to use compile-time type checking to differentiate between the two? Do they have other non-identical data members? If they don't, you probably would want to simply add a `bool forProfit` member to the `Company` class, with no need for subtypes.

Comment: or use pure virtual methods to force two subclasses to implement the getter for those two members

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A non-profit company is a company, a for-profit company is a company, but a company is not a name, and it is not a date of formation, instead a company has a name and date of formation.

"Is a" relation is inheritance. "Has a" relation is aggregation.

If both companies share the same members, then those should be in the base class, because code reuse is one of the main ideas of inheritance (aside from polymorphism)

```
class Company {
protected:
    Company(QString n, QDate df) : name(n), dateFormed(df) { } // protected constructor, can't create a Company instance
    QString name; // protected data members, cannot be accidentally changed
    QDate dateFormed;
public:
    virtual ~Company() {} // you always need a virtual destructor for polymorphism
    virtual void info() = 0; // abstract method, must be implemented in order to instantiate derived classes    
};

class NonProfit : public Company {
public:
    NonProfit(QString n, QDate df) : Company(n, df) { }
    void info() { qDebug() << "Non-profit company" << name << "formed on" << dateFormed; }
};

class ForProfit : public Company {
public:
    ForProfit(QString n, QDate df) : Company(n, df) { }
    void info() { qDebug() << "For-profit company" << name << "formed on" << dateFormed; }
};
```

And usage:

```
Company cp("some company", QDateTime::currentDateTime().date()); // won't work
NonProfit np("some company", QDateTime::currentDateTime().date());
np.info(); // Non-profit company "some company" formed on 2015-08-15
```

Polymorphism in action:

```
Company * c1 = new NonProfit("some company", QDateTime::currentDateTime().date());
Company * c2 = new ForProfit("some company", QDateTime::currentDateTime().date());
c1->info(); // Non-profit company "some company" formed on 2015-08-15
c2->info(); // For-profit company "some company" formed on 2015-08-15
```

Also note that even though the derive classes don't have declared virtual destructors, and info is not explicitly virtual, C++ will automatically generate virtual destructors as long as the base class has a declared virtual destructor, and the info will also be implicitly virtual, some people prefer to write methods as virtual in derived classes for clarity, but once virtual in the base class, a method will be implicitly virtual in the derived classes as well.

Comment: Thanks @ddriver that's a very clear/understandable explanation.  forProfit and notForprofit both have some unique members so could I initialize forProfit like this forProfit::forProfit(QString name, QDate date, int employees) : Company(name, date), m_employees(employees) {}?

Comment: @user2094257 - yes, that's the way to go. Naturally, if all companies have employees, that should go into the base class as well.

Comment: Just a comment for the last note: since C++11, you can use the `override` specifier for this purpose in the derived class methods, which also ensures at compile-time that it's actually overriding the base class method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the relationship between base and derived is "is a", everything the base class have, it derived classes have.

code snippet:

```
// derived classes
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon 
{
protected:
int width, height;

public:
    void set_values (int a, int b) 
    { 
       width=a; 
       height=b;
    }
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon 
{
public:
    int area ()
    { 
         return width * height; 
    }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon 
{
public:
   int area ()
   {  
      return width * height / 2; 
   }
};
```

Comment: I was nervus becuse its my first anser and i need the up-vots for reputtion, i copy-past from some cpp site :)

Comment: Well, it is a bad example, neither a polygon nor a triangle is defined by width and height. That only applies to rectangles. You should have implemented what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Anyhow my answer, answers the question

Comment: Can you at the very least credit your source: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/. You may want to review our [rules on how to cite](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).